# View a file whilst it is being written - Python

Tags: python

I am making a game in python 2.7 for fun and am trying to make a map to go along with it. I am using file I/O to read and write the map and have also got notepad ++ set to silent update, however I can only see the changes once my program has fully run and want to view the file as it is updated.

I have this code which i am testing with:

```
from time import sleep

map = open('C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\Codes\Python RPG\Maps\map.txt', 'r+')
map.truncate()
print "file deleted"

sleep(1)

worldMap = open('C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\Codes\Python RPG\Maps\worldMap.txt', 'r')
for line in worldMap:
    map.write(line)
print "file updated"

worldMap.close()
map.close()
```

Any help is greatly appricated :)

Comment: python only writes to file once it has been closed

Comment: with the .close() method

Comment: It is stored in a buffer during runtime and when .close() is called the buffer is sent to the file system, it is they way it works due to implementation of the bus system on computers, if i remember correctly, not just a "lazy" reason

Comment: You want `os.fsync`

Comment: @Mixone That's not quite correct. The `file.flush()` method can be used to force Python to write the buffer to the file. `file.close()` automatically flushes the file, though.

Comment: @Ryan, Webb, why are you opening with r+ and then calling truncate?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I wrote that `os.fsync` is not needed. Depending on how Notepad++ works, this might be wrong. I'm going to delete the comment (editing is not possible anymore). But still the file has to be flushed before calling `os.fsync`.

Comment: @ManuelJacob aha! thanks, I was going to say .close flushes it but then had a small moment of doubt so decided not to mention, right, good to know now :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Python uses buffered I/O.  This means that written data is stored in memory before actually written to the file.  Calling file's [`flush`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.flush) method causes the data to be written to the file.

Comment: Do i need to have focus on the file to see the updates? As its not currently working. I added map.flush() and os.fsync(map.fileno()) whenever i want to see a change

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know exactly how Notepad++ works and how it gets the update. But doing a quick Internet search suggests that you must focus the tab to see the updates. There's not much you can do from the Python side.

Comment: The latest version, which was released 11 days ago, added a new "Monitoring" feature: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.9.2-released.html I hope this helps.